# Converting from Pbgra32 to Bgr32 PixelFormats using FormatConvertedBitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, writeablebitmap, writeablebitmapex

I am having trouble understanding how to use `FormatConvertedBitmap` to convert a `WriteableBitmap` I have from `Pbgra32` to `Bgr32`. The application I'm building was initially using Bgr32, and I introduced `WriteableBitmapEx` (which uses Pbgra32) to flip an image. Now, I need to convert from `Pbgra32` back to `Bgr32` to maintain consistency with the rest of the program. The following is what I have:

```
FormatConvertedBitmap newFormat = new FormatConvertedBitmap(this.colorBitmap, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, 0);
```

...which I believe to be correct for doing the conversion. However, I am unsure how to retrieve a WriteableBitmap from this.

Comment: Couldn't you just create a new WriteableBitmap by passing `newFormat` to [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa346377.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, you just have to cast it to a `WriteableBitmap` so you can store it as one. And to do this, you have to cast it to a `BitmapSource` first and create a new `WriteableBitmap`. So something like this:

```
WriteableBitmap yourConvertedPicture = new WriteableBitmap(
   (BitmapSource)(new FormatConvertedBitmap(thePictureToConvert, PixelFormats.Bgr32, null, 0))
);
```

This will also work for converting to any other `PixelFormat`